# Why am I getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a NSTimer selector?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, exc-bad-access

I've got quite a weird problem. To make it short, i'll write some pseudo-code:

```
init: create a dictionary and insert n elements.
      create a "repeat timer" and add it to the currentRunLoop using the timerRefresh selector.

timerRefresh: using a list of keys, find the items in the dictionary
              if the item exists -> call a function
```

So, for an unknown reason, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I do:

```
    [item function];
```

But I traced the address I got from the dictionary items and it's ok. The ref count of the items in the dictionary is still 1. The {release, dealloc} of the items in the dictionary aren't called. Everything seems fine. Also, to make it worst, it works for some items.

So, I'm wondering if there is a threading problem? or something else obscure?

The callstack is quite simple:

```
#0  0x93e0604b in objc_msgSend_fpret
#1  0x00f3e6b0 in ??
#2  0x0001cfca in -[myObject timerRefresh:] at myObject.m:000
#3  0x305355cd in __NSFireTimer
#4  0x302454a0 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#5  0x30244628 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#6  0x32044c31 in GSEventRunModal
#7  0x32044cf6 in GSEventRun
#8  0x309021ee in UIApplicationMain
#9  0x000027e0 in main at main.m:14
```

So, any suggestion where to look would be appreciated.

--- Edit #1 ---

@Laurent: It's a typo of me rewriting the actual value to match my example. (fixed)

@Jeremy: I will try to post some code to help. The code has been simplified.

Timer Init + Refresh Function:

```
_refreshTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5] interval:5
                                 target:self selector:@selector(onTimerRefresh:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_refreshTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

//...

 (void)onTimerRefresh:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
      // the actual code is here. I will rewrite it so it's simpler:
     for (MyKey key in keys) {
         MyObject* object = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
         if (object)
             [object function];
     }
 }
```

I hope it's a little bit clearer.

right, I've commented everything in my "function" and it looks like it doesn't crash. I'll let it run a little more but I'm not doing anything special in that function (memory related). Just updating some enum values.

--- Edit #2 ---

@Laurent: you are right about the callstak, I made a huge mistake. It should be the timer method and not the function. I just fix it. Sorry for the mistake. But FYI, the method signature is:

```
- (bool)update;
```

Comment: There is a mismatch between the call to "function" method and the stack trace where there is "functionm:". Is it ok ?

Can you also post some relevant code ?

Comment: @Laurent +about a million for "post some relevant code"

Comment: @AngeDeLaMort:  some questions:  what do you mean by the "timerRefresh" selector?  There is no such selector on NSTimer. There's no timerRefresh in your stack trace.  Where do you get the list of keys?  Please post the code of the timer initialisation and scheduling in the run loop and what happens when the timer fires.

Comment: Can you post the definition of the "function" method. From the stack-trace, it expects one parameter but you don't pass one.

Comment: Does the dictionary change while the timer is active?

Comment: @Georg: no, the dictionary doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found what was the problem. In the method "update"

```
- (bool)update {
    // ...
    NSDate* now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceNow] - [creation timeIntervalSinceNow];
    //...
}
```

The problem was that I didn't do a retain on the date (creation) in the init. I don't really understand why the object got "corrupted", but I think the debugger should had pointed that variable and not the function call...

I'll let the application run for a while to see if the crash is gone.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to get the date of right now you can just do `now = [NSDate date];`